# How to disable console host on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

Since Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 everytime you open a console program, the system opens another process called conhost.exe, to apply windows themes and enable the drag&drop functionality to that console window.
Provided that on a server system windows themes are disabled, that I won't ever use the drag&drop functionality, that each of this process takes at least 2 MB of RAM and, most important, according to sysinternals process explorer each conhost.exe process has more than 2500-3000 context switches per second (thus reducing the performance of the whole system), I would like to restore the old behaviour of windows 2008/vista and disable conhost.exe entirely.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it isn't possible: from 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/10/05/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-console-host.aspx

*ConHost represents a permanent change in the way that console application I/O is handled.  There is no registry key or group policy setting that can force Windows to revert back to “legacy mode” console behavior.*

Comment: Thx Micro$oft i had limit on one VPS to 70 process so time to move to linux bacause 20 conhost.exe is tooomuch